# System Resources for Update Statement

Tags: ms-access, database-performance

I am working in MS Access 2013.  I have a table with 20K records being updated from another table.  Is Access robust enough to allow me to update 10 fields in one query or should I break them into separate statements?

The update is going to be occurring at least twice a week to bring in new and changed data.

Thanks!

Comment: How bog are the fields, and what data type?

Comment: Sorry, the surface rt sometimes hides what I'm typing - that should be 'big'

Comment: Fields are all Short Text with a field size of 255.

Comment: Your best answer may be to write the query with one field, and then add fields while watching your query times.  Based on my experience with 1 GB Access databases, we never had problems with just 10 fields.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response!